# How to use a Set type with custom objects as datasource

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to use my

```
var savings = Set<Saving>()
```

as Data source in my UITableView.

I can't use something like

```
cell.name = savings[indexPath.row].name
```

Because the subscript is only Saving. Is there a way to do this anyway?

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is something like:

```
var savings = Array<Saving>()
```

and then call it as

```
cell.name = savings[indexPath.row].name
```

**Update**

if you have  savings as `Set`. you can get array out of it and use it like this:

```
let savingsArray = Array(savings)
```

and then call it as

```
cell.name = savingsArray[indexPath.row].name
```

Comment: I am getting it as a set that is why I need to use Set

Comment: Note that if you have a large set that is dynamically updated, then, for this method, there will be an overhead to repeatedly create an `Array` representation of the `Set` each time you wish to access some properties from it (via simulated ordered access). I'd recommend either using `Array` to begin with, or to find alternative approaches.

Comment: @dfri I think in Reshad case it is only needed to be converted to array once. otherwise, finding an alternative approach is better.

Answer (score 1):

Set's are inherently unordered, but UITableViewDataSource implementations are required to have a defined ordering. You'll have to convert the set to an Array (which has a defined ordering) and use that to implement the data source methods.

Answer (score 1):

I should first mention that perhaps `Set` is not the best collection type for you in this case, as---as mentioned by Bill---`Set` is inherently unordered.

---

You can, however, access the `name` property of a `Saving` instance by matching the `indexPath.row` integer property to integer `id` property in your `Saving` class / structure, making use of `Set` method `.filter(...)`.

Consider the following example. We first create a `Saving` structure (or class, as I gather you have) that conforms to `Hashable` and `Equatable` protocols, to be eligible as members of collection type `Set`:

```
/* Saving: conform to Hashable and Equatable for use as 
   collection type Set members */
struct Saving : Hashable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String

    /* Make Saving conform to Hashable */
    var hashValue: Int {
        return self.id
    }

    init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

/* Make Saving conform to Equtable */
func ==(lhs: Saving, rhs: Saving) -> Bool {
    return lhs.id == rhs.id
}
```

Now, consider the following example, of accessing specific members of you `Set` (of type `Saving`) given a integer id, e.g. such as corresponding row index (`indexPath.row`) in your table view:

```
/* Example */
var savings = Set<Saving>()

savings.insert(Saving(id: 1, name: "Savings A"))
savings.insert(Saving(id: 2, name: "Savings B"))
savings.insert(Saving(id: 3, name: "Savings C"))

let indexPathRow = 1 // for our example

var cellName = savings.filter({ $0.id == indexPathRow }).first?.name ?? "No such Savings id"

print(cellName) // Savings A
```

Alternatively, create the `.name` by `.id` extraction as a function.

```
func getSavingsName(mySavingsSet: Set<Saving>, myId: Int) -> String {
    return mySavingsSet.filter({ $0.id == myId }).first?.name ?? "No such Savings id"
}

/* for your specific example */
cell.name = getSavingsName(savings, myId: indexPath.row)
```

Preferably handle the case *"No such Saving id"* using optional return instead, to avoid running into any undetermined behaviour when (trying to) find members of your `Set` corresponding to row id:s of your table view.